# Ember.js: How to load a large model without blocking UI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am loading a large model (2500 entries) in Ember Data from an API.
It also takes 3 HTTP Requests since the server will only return 1000 results at a time.

My whole web browser freezes for a moment while it is loading, which begs the question:

**What is the best way to load large models without blocking the UI?**

I tried `beginPropertyChanges`, `endPropertyChanges`:

```
Ember.RSVP.resolve(store.beginPropertyChanges())
  .then(getAllTeams)  // this loads the model
  .then(function() { return Ember.RSVP.resolve(store.endPropertyChanges()); });


var getAllTeams = function(teams, skip) {
    if (!teams) {
        return store.find('team', {limit:1000, skip: 0}).then(function(foundTeams) {
            var teams = foundTeams;
            return getAllTeams(foundTeams,teams.get('length'));
        });
    }
    else if (teams.get('length') < 1000) {
        return store.find('team');
    }
    else {
        return store.find('team', {limit: 1000, skip:skip}).then(function(foundTeams) {
            return getAllTeams(foundTeams,skip+teams.get('length'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use Ember Data for it?  Are you performing CRUD operations on the teams?  Or is it just Read.  If it's just read, I'd skip the overhead of Ember Data and just use POJOs.  Additionally, are they all being shown at once in the UI, is it the UI that's taking forever, or is it the building up of models, or fetching the models?

Comment: yes initially it is just read.  i like the idea of them being managed, persisted locally though so would I just read using POJOs and then push them into the store asynchronously/in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `beginPropertyChanges` on the store is not going to accomplish anything useful at all.

The default behavior of Ember is that yes, it will block on large downloads. Here is a possible approach.

```
// route
export default Ember.Route.extend({

 model: function() { 
   var all = return this.store.all('team'); 
   function get_more(n) {
     return store.find('team', {limit:1000, skip: n}) . 
       then(function(teams) { 
         if (teams.length === 1000) return get_more(n+1000); 
       })
   }(0));
   return all;
});
```

We return a live collection of teams in the store, which initially might be zero. Asynchronously to that, we start a loop which gets items 1000 at a time. As the new items come in, the live collection will be updated and the relevant UI will as well.

Untested.

Answer (score 0):

Ember provides a mechanism for handling long route render times. I believe what you are looking for is [Loading / Error Substates](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

Check out official EmberJS guide pages.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Great, now I can watch a spinning wheel while my data loads.